# How to compare same cell and another for differences

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

basically I want to check rows in excel (automatically), scan a full database and return the rows where the values in one column are the same and in another aren’t the same.

Example:

```
A B C
-----
1 7 2
2 8 4
1 8 3
1 7 4
2 6 3
```

Would check and return a table like this(check A for similarities and B for differences)

```
A
1
2
```

Comment: From your example it shows `check A for similarities` means extract unique values. But what do you mean by`B for differences`?

Comment: Exactly what I meant, check A for similarities and extract unique values from B, is it possible to do?

Comment: Then what would be output from `B` column? Put an screenshot of sheet with your input data and output data.

Comment: Output would be a table showing first column the value in A and the rest (each unique column) is the unique value stored in B, so A, B, B, B, B, B. The highest number of unique values there can be for B is 5